# Call multiple quit points in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

```html
#!/bin/sh
echo "Kaveen's TCP Redirect SCRIPT"
clear
read -p "Port:" port
echo ""
read -p "Customer IP:" cusip
echo ""
read -p "Your Filtered IP:" filip
echo ""
read -p "Your Secondary IP:" secip
echo "Generating TCP Redirect on port $port from your ip $filip to customer ip $cusip"
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d $filip --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination $cusip
echo "TCP Redirect 1/2 OK"
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
echo "TCP Redirect 2/2 OK"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d $cusip -j SNAT --to-source $secip
echo "Better Traffic Movement rule 1/1 OK"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source $filip
echo "Player Movement Rule 1/1 OK"
echo "Generating reset script...."
echo "#!/bin/sh" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t nat -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t nat -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t nat -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t nat -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -F" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -X" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
echo "iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT" >> reset.sh
chmod +x reset.sh
echo "Reset script creation OK"
echo "Reset script can be used via ./reset.sh in directory:"
pwd
echo "TCP Redirect made from $fillip to $cusip on port $port"
```

I've made an iptables TCP Redirect script as above.
I want to make it so that, for example if one of the iptables commands fails, to stop the script right there and not run any of the stuff below it, how can I do this?

Comment: by the way, you can make things much more beautiful by replacing your 100 strings with a single multiline string literal.

Comment: and how would one do that?

Comment: using google, typing in *multiline string literal bash*, seriously.

Comment: I come here for detailed answers, not to go wallbang google for minutes just to find some bad explanation for it.

Comment: "wallbang for minutes" wow. MINUTES! LIKE REAL, MORE THAN 60s OF AUTONOMOUS WORK!

Comment: Google is unreliable. I rather get answers from people who know what they're doing, like you, per se, instead of just googling for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is probably to add the errexit option.  That is most easily accomplished in the shebang:

```
echo "#!/bin/sh -e" >> reset.sh
```

But you really ought to consider using a heredoc for the whole script:

```
cat << \EOF > reset.sh
#!/bin/sh -e
iptables -F
iptables -X
...
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
EOF
```